# Rewriting shortcode through url parameters

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

The thing is I have a WordPress page with a number of trips, and each trip has inserted a specific contact form (because it varies depending on dates, accommodations, etc.). The plugin used is “Contact Form 7”.

Now we want to give the option to book directly, which also involves providing details of the travelers (age, date of birth, etc.). I mean, through a button in the contact form, he would be directed to another page only with the form and with the same options as the first one but also adding the boxes to enter information for each traveler.

The first objective is not having to duplicate all the forms with the “booking version”, which is something I have achieved through the “Contact Form 7 Conditional Fields” plugin; all the information about the number of travelers is already included in the original contact form, but not shown if one of the fields is not filled with the text “Book the tour”. Then when you click on “I want to book the trip” it sends you to another page with the same form but which this text included, so It unhide the rest of the fields, using url parameters:

Trip-booking/?Header=Book%20the%trip

Now comes the second problem that I know not how to solve. The only content in the “book page” is a simple shortcode text, like this:
[Contact-form-7 id = “001” title = “Journey 1”]

So I have to make a page for each form, which is irritated.

My question is if there’s any way to “rewrite” the content dynamically via parameters url, so that if I put in the link this:

Trip-booking/?Header=Book%20the%trip?form=001

The page would have this code:

[Contact-form-7 id = “001”]

And if I type this another url for example:

Trip-booking/?Header=Book%20the%trip?form=002

The page would have this code:

[Contact-form-7 id = “002”]

So I have no idea of how to formalize it to avoid creating a specific page for each shortcode.

Obviously I’m open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the formID from the URL and call do_shortcode.

`$formId = $_GET['form'];
do_shortcode('[Contact-form-7 id="'.$formId.'"]');`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: Sorry, but I have to be honest I have no idea what I have to do with that code. Do I have to put it exactly in the destination page? Because I have tried to, and nothing happens (only that exactly that text appears).

So I guess I have to put it in some way in the page where the contact form shortcode must be edit dinamically, isnt it? and then change what it shows through url parameters like "Trip-booking/?form=002"

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes. You should just be able to put that code in. You will need to ensure it is inside PHP tags otherwise it will just be rendered as HTML. Here an the example from the contact form 7 website. 
http://contactform7.com/faq/can-i-embed-a-contact-form-into-my-template-file/

Comment: The thing is I'm trying it with no results. If I put this in one page:

<?php
$formId = $_GET['form'];
do_shortcode('[Contact-form-7 id="'.$formId.'"]');
?>

nothing happens (no contact form is shown)

Even if I put something more simple like:

<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="1234" title="Contact form 1"]' ); ?>

Nothing happens.

Why could it be?

Comment: If you put the shortcode into the post content via the edit post does the form appear?

Comment: Yes. Contact form shortcodes have been always worked perfectly in posts